# User Session cookies process_Nodejs /passport

Tags: node.js, passport.js, session-cookies

I'm trying to create session - cookies in order to maintain user login and then do some authorization to some content but the problem that this system is too complex , session , cookies , storage'memory'

cause I read in many sites that Session-only cookies,  stores information in the browser memory, and is available for the duration of the browser session. In other words, the data stored inside a session cookie is available from the time of storage until the browser is closed. Moving from page to page during this time does not erase the data.

What I'm trying to use is create session for every user using passport using the configuration below but I didn"t succeed ,

the code sessions is  below `app.js`

```
require('./models/db')
const express = require('express');
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passport = require('passport');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const session = require('express-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app = express();

// Passport Config
require('./config/passport')(passport);


// EJS
app.use(expressLayouts);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use('/public/uploads',express.static(__dirname + '/public/uploads'))
// Express body parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// Express session
app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
  })
);

// Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Connect flash
app.use(flash());

// Global variables
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
  res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
  res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
  next();
});

// Routes
app.use('/', require('./routes/index.js'));
app.use('/gallery',require('./routes/gallery.js'));
app.use('/users', require('./routes/users.js'));
app.use('/me', require('./routes/publish.js'))
app.use('/api',require('./routes/ChangePassword'));
app.use('/post', require('./routes/home.js'))
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

and the routes for the `user.js` for the login is below

```
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/users/home',
    failureRedirect: '/users/login',
    failureFlash: true
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Any recommandation  on How achieving it using an efficient process ?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, when using express.js, the order of middleware matters. You are using EJS middleware before passport.js. That's why your pages are being rendered before session is initialized.

Comment: small things always matter :D, Yes I noticed that

Comment: yes it is working just moved that passport statement but can I ask you question please?

Comment: yeah, sure. I'll try to answer as much as I can

Comment: thank you, do you have an idea how can I do the authorization part using that session like,   user can only access specific content

Comment: Of course. You need to implement role based authorization. Here are two links: 1. https://blog.soshace.com/implementing-role-based-access-control-in-a-node-js-application/ 2. https://youtu.be/jI4K7L-LI58

Comment: Thank you so much, do u have a fb account that I can reach you if I got newbie question like this ?

Comment: Yeah, it's https://fb.com/sheikhMishar . It may take some time to reply...